# Sort pandas dataframe columns on second row order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I need to sort a dataframe based on the order of the second row.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1a': ['C', 3, 1], '2b': ['B', 2, 3], '3c': ['A', 5, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Output:

```
  1a 2b 3c
0  C  B  A
1  3  2  5
2  1  3  2
```

Desired output:

```
  3c 2b 1a
0  A  B  C
1  5  2  3
2  2  3  1
```

So the columns have been order based on the zero index row, on the A, B, C.

Have tried many sorting options without success.

Having a quick way to accomplish this would be beneficial, but having granular control to both order the elements and move a specific column to the first position would be even better.  For example move "C" to the first column.

Something like make a list, sort, move and reorder on list.

```
mylist = ['B', 'A', 'C']
mylist.sort()
mylist.insert(0, mylist.pop(mylist.index('C')))
```

Then sorting the dataframe on ['C', 'A', 'B'] outputting

```
  1a 3c 2b
0  C  A  B
1  3  5  2
2  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of pyjedy and Stingher, I was able to resolve this issue. One of the problems was due to my input. The input consisted of lists instead of dictionaries, so I needed to transform it. As a result, I had indexes for rows and across the top for columns. Consequently, selecting elements from the list required obtaining the index.

```
import pandas as pd

def search_list_for_pattern(lst, pattern):
    for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
        if pattern in item:
            break
    return idx

data = [['1a', 'B', 2, 3], ['2b', 'C', 3, 1], ['3c', 'A', 5, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
print(df)

#     0   1   2
# 0  1a  2b  3c
# 1   B   C   A
# 2   2   3   5
# 3   3   1   2

# Get the second row and convert it to a list
second_row = df.iloc[1, :].tolist()
print(second_row)

# ['B', 'C', 'A']

# Find the index of the column you want to move to the first position
target_column = search_list_for_pattern(second_row, "C")
print(target_column)

# 1

# Sort the list
sorted_columns = sorted(range(len(second_row)), key=lambda k: second_row[k])
print(sorted_columns)

# [2, 0, 1]

# Move the target column to the first position
sorted_columns.remove(df.columns.get_loc(target_column))
sorted_columns.insert(0, df.columns.get_loc(target_column))

# Reorder the columns of the DataFrame based on the sorted list
df = df.iloc[:, sorted_columns]
print(df)

#     1   2   0
# 0  2b  3c  1a
# 1   C   A   B
# 2   3   5   2
# 3   1   2   3

df.to_excel('ordered.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
df = df[df.iloc[0].sort_values().index]
```

Returning:

```
  3c 2b 1a
0  A  B  C
1  5  2  3
2  2  3  1
```

In this case you are working with the first row, and sorting it to then return the index values in the sorted. You have a lot flexibility you can even sort by multiple columns/rows this way too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move a specific column to the first position, you can modify the code as in example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"1a": ["C", 3, 1],
        "2b": ["B", 2, 3],
        "3c": ["A", 5, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#   1a 2b 3c
# 0  C  B  A
# 1  3  2  5
# 2  1  3  2

# Get the second row and convert it to a list
second_row = df.iloc[1, :].tolist()
print(second_row)
# [3, 2, 5]

# Define the column you want to move to the first position
target_column = "1a"

# Sort the list
sorted_columns = sorted(range(len(second_row)), key=lambda k: second_row[k])
print(sorted_columns)

# Move the target column to the first position
sorted_columns.remove(df.columns.get_loc(target_column))
sorted_columns.insert(0, df.columns.get_loc(target_column))

# Reorder the columns of the DataFrame based on the sorted list
df = df.iloc[:, sorted_columns]

print(df)
#   1a 2b 3c
# 0  C  B  A
# 1  3  2  5
# 2  1  3  2
```